# How to remove extra zeros from money fields in PHP using SQLSRV driver?

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I recently started migrating my PHP application from a Unix infrastructure to a Windows based infrastructure, and part of this transition is moving from mssql_connect to sqlsrv_connect for the DB interactions. For the most part this has been painless, aside from changing the SQL driver in the DAL, we're aiming for minimal changes to the overall codebase.

One issue I noticed out of the gate was by default, date columns are returned as PHP date objects. While this is nice, we've already coded logic to handle string dates and fortunately we were able to flag an option to return date as a string. This matches the behavior of the old MSSQL driver.

However, now we're seeing issues with money datatype fields being returned with two extra zeroes at the end. For example, this query in SQL studio:

```
select applied_amt from transaction_detail_071515 where batch = '0000521'
```

Returns:

```
applied_amt
52.00
```

However, when I run the same through PHP, I get the following result:

```
applied_amt
52.0000
```

Notice the extra zeroes at the end. Even amounts with non-zero cents return the extra zeroes:

```
1825.4200
```

I don't see any options in the documentation to revert to the old behavior. I could account for this in the front end application, however the way our application works makes this difficult, as it's designed to output these fields "as-is" from the database. Not all of the fields are amounts, some are dates and others simply strings. Modifying that logic to trim trailing zeroes from amounts only would be difficult and is a large development effort.

Is there any way to change the SQL SRV driver behavior to not pull in trailing zeroes?

Comment: The money datatype has 4 decimal places. If you want a different datatype you will need to change the datatype of the column, cast the output to the datatype you want or handle the formatting in the front end.

Comment: So is the older MSSQL driver just "incorrect"? It never returned 4 decimal places before.

Comment: The money datatype hasn't changed since at least 6.5 when I started working with sql server. Maybe something has changed on the PHP side of things. I can barely spell PHP let alone have any knowledge of it. I wish I had an answer for you. I would suggest either formatting the results or using a decimal datatype instead of the legacy money datatype.